# Nodejs heroku h12

Tags: node.js, heroku, cluster-computing, pm2

we run an app an Heroku with 2 dynos "Standart 2 (1GB RAM)" + Redis Premium with 80 COnnections. When we test our app with 5-6 users, who generate a lot of requests, we get H12 and H13 errors. We start our app with "pm2 start server.js -i 4 --no-deamon". The test with 1 dyno "Standart 1" was better!

What are we doing wrong? Is it allright to start app with pm2 for cluster the app?

In "papertrail" can we see, what all of 4 Node-instances doing their job!

Answer (score 0):

With the 2x dyno it might be worth to try clustering. More information: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-concurrency

Also, when processing large amounts of data, Node streams will help reduce the amount of data loaded on RAM at once. For instance, I was able to handle 7 times the amount of concurrent requests before running out of memory by implementing streams in my Node.js app hosted on Heroku.